# Work Item Only View - View All Work Items

Tags: tfs, tfs-workitem, tfs-web-access

I have users in the [Work Item Only View].  Is there a way to let them see all work items instead of just the items they submitted?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No.  The TFS work item only view is there [only to allow you to enforce CAL licensing](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc668124.aspx).

Work Item Only View allows any user, without a TFS Client Access License (CAL), to access TFS for the specific purpose of creating work items and viewing work items that they've created.

In order for users to see *all* work items, they will need a CAL.  At that point, they should not be a user in Work Item Only View, you should just create a group that has the [appropriate permissions](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms252587.aspx) to view work items.

Comment: Thanks Edward.  After doing some more reading it all makes since.  I'm just a little unsure on what would be the appropriate permissions for the new group.